# Appointment deletion fails, possibly due to AppointmentItem being null?

Tags: vba, outlook

```
Sub AutoCancel(ByRef Item As Outlook.MeetingItem)

  Dim strID As String
  Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim oMeetingItem As Outlook.MeetingItem
  Dim oResponse As Outlook.MeetingItem
  Dim oAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem

  strID = Item.EntryID

  Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set oMeetingItem = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)
  Set oAppointment = oMeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment(False)

 oAppointment.Delete

  Set oAppointment = Nothing
  Set oMeetingItem = Nothing
  Set olNS = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have emails for appointments/cancellations coming in bulk to users that I'd like to automatically accept or cancel and then delete from their inbox. The accept method seems to work, but this method sends a debug report to the user for each cancellation pointing to the `oAppointment.Delete` line. 
My thought is that it's erroring out under some circumstance where oMeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment is returning null, so it has nothing to delete. This is just a hunch though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you pass false to GetAssociatedAppointment, it will **not** create an appointment if it does not already exist.

Comment: Under the circumstances of when this macro is ran, there always is an appointment that exists. When doing testing I can see the appointments on my calendar that the cancellations are for. Do you have any idea what would cause this if that is the case?

Comment: Run-time error '91':
    Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: And this is what really confuses me...it will give that error message and ask if I want to debug. The debug will then point to the Delete line. Yet when I close the debug, it successfully deletes the appointment! This wouldn't be that big of a deal if it wasn't for the fact that people will be cancelling large numbers of appointments at one time and get like 20-50 error windows.

Comment: So when you step through the code, is oAppointment variable null?